# Pause and Resume PostgreSQL Connection on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, asynchronous, pg

How can I successfully pause and resume a DB connection for PostgreSQL/node.js? This is the idea of what I want to achieve :

```
query
.on('error', function(err) {
    // Handle error
})
.on('row', function(row) {
    // Process a row but first pause connection so it wont keep getting into 'row' event and finish processing this row first
    pgconnection.pause();

    async.series([
      functions()
    ])

    pgconnection.resume();
})
.on('end', function() {
    //Rows have been received and finish
});
```

Right now I've been exploring pg and pg-query-stream modules but havent got any luck yet. The main objective is to complete every single async function inside 'row' event before moving out to the next 'row' event or 'end' event.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at it the wrong way, trying to apply synchronous restrictions to asynchronous code. It won't work. And even if it did, the result would be bad, non-scalable.

What you should do instead, is getting familiar with [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/), which is the answer to your problem.

> The main objective is to complete every single async function

The standard [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) does that.

> I've been exploring `pg` and `pg-query-stream` modules but havent got any luck yet

`pg` is an asynchronous module, and `pg-query-stream` is supposed to work as fast as possible, because it is a stream. You don't block streams, that's not not how they work. If your code logic cannot handle the way data is paged from the stream, then something is wrong with your code, not the stream provider. Then again, learn promises and how to use them properly.